# Comparing two images with features extracted from a CNN

Tags: neural-network, feature-extraction

I'm trying to compare two images (the first one is the ID's image and the second one is a selfie taken by phone) so I am wondering if can we extract features from the two images by using CNN and comparing the two vectors by using the cosine  or the Euclidean distance.
sift and Gabor didn't show a good result

Comment: a CNN mapping an image to an embedding vector could work indeed